# How to get the Bit value by index from NSData Hex value in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, hex, byte, nsdata, bit

I have a `NSData` of `Hex`

> <80140142 0073ffff ffff04ff>

I can get the `Byte` value by index

> NSData *commandIDData = [mqttResponseData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,1)];
>   <42> // 66

How Can I get the `Bit` value by index?

> 0100 0010

e.g

> index[0]=0
>   index[1]=1
>   index[2]=0
>   index[4]=0

Comment: What's your purpose? You can use bitmask if needed.

Comment: @Lamre I need all the Bit value as they are isActive Status for 6 Chanel and they are Boolean. I used Bitmask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSData *statusData = [mqttResponseData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,1)];

const unsigned char *statusByte = [statusData bytes];//Hex<4F>/Decimal-79/Binary-01001111

for (int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++) {
    bool chanelValue = [[NSNumber numberWithChar:(*statusByte >> i) & 0x01] boolValue];//i = 0 right most bit
    NSLog(@"chanelValue %d: %d",i+1,chanelValue);//1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
}
```